# Is there a way to get curl output into a file?

Tags: curl

Here is the script on the Linux:

```
if [ -s $WORK_DIR/newerfile ]
then
    curl -k -T $WORK_DIR/newerfile -u username:password ftpssl.example.bank/inbound
fi
```

I want to get the results of the curl command into a file that I can save. We are sending a file to a bank and want to make sure the file gets there.  I have used just this command at a Linux prompt and it 'appeared' to work (no errors) but I didn't see any output. I read the curl faqs and I know about the progress meter - and it does indicate that you can use the shell > to a file but as I saw no output, I just don't know.  And I really know very little about curl.

Comment: please read the [man page for curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) and take a look at the `-o` option.  If that will not work for what you need please update the question with further details.

Answer (score 7):

From the [curl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

```
-o, --output <file>
              Write output to <file> instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#'
              followed by a number in the <file> specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL
              being fetched. Like in:

                curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"

              or use several variables like:

                curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"

              You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.

              See also the --create-dirs option to create the local directories dynamically. Specifying the output as  '-'  (a
              single dash) will force the output to be done to stdout.
```

If you are merely wanting to check if the command was successful or not, just check curl's exit code. It'll be 0 if successful and something else if not.